# .htaccess file causing error on localhost

Tags: .htaccess, localhost

This is my .htaccess file code which is located in the root of localhost, without it works fine, so there's something wrong with it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRUl .* /index.php [L]
```

I get the following error message when trying to load any page:

> SERVER ERROR!
> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.
> [...]
> 06/07/2013 12:34:52 p.m.
> Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.3.1 mod_apreq2-20090110/2.7.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1

Comment: you have a typo; the 5th line should be `RewriteRule ...`

Answer (score 0):

The error was on the last line of the .htaccess file, bad grammar, it should be:

```
RewriteRule .* /index.php [L]
```

Thanks anyway :-)